# Is there way to return null valued rows when when querying joined table

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite

I have two tables: `users` table with `id`, `name` columns and `events` table with `id`, `content` and `userId` columns.

I am trying to query a table that return joined information from these two tables with `name` and `events` columns where `events` would represent an array of `content` fields corresponding to a user.

This is the query I am running:

```
select 
    name, group_concat(content) as events 
from 
    users 
left join 
    events on id = userId 
group by 
    userId 
order by 
    id
```

However rows with `null` values are not being returned except of just one row. What am I doing wrong?

Users table

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Hugo Powlowski"
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Jeremy Littel II"
},
{
"id": 3,
"name": "Eleanor King"
},
{
"id": 4,
"name": "Rogelio Jacobson"
},
{
"id": 5,
"name": "Jerald Rowe PhD"
},
{
"id": 6,
"name": "Robyn Tromp"
},
{
"id": 7,
"name": "Norman Zboncak"
},
{
"id": 8,
"name": "Mr. Kristy Orn"
},
{
"id": 9,
"name": "Mrs. Olivia Trantow"
},
{
"id": 10,
"name": "Daniel Lebsack"
}
]
```

Events table

```
[
{
"eventId": 3,
"content": "hello",
"userId": 7
},
{
"eventId": 12,
"content": "rulsan berden",
"userId": 1
}
]
```

Joined table

```
[
{
"name": "Hugo Powlowski",
"events": "rulsan berden"
},
{
"name": "Jeremy Littel II",
"events": null
},
{
"name": "Norman Zboncak",
"events": "hello"
}
]
```

Comment: please post sample data - as text

Comment: You should qualify all columns with their tables, i.e. `on users.id = events.userId` instead of `on id = userId`, so the DBMS knows which ID you are talking about. Apart from this the query looks fine and should return all users.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner  thank you for the response. Please note the Barmar's answer below - that's the right answer

Comment: Yes, I didn't see this. I might have, had all columns been qualified with the tables as mentioned. Then it would become more obvious that you are grouping on a column of the outer-joined table. Always qualify all columns when working with more than one table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should group by the column in the parent table, not the table being left joined, so that the values will never be null.

So change `GROUP BY userid` to `GROUP BY users.id`.

Comment: thank you sir. I spent 3 days exploring sql and trying to find an answer. I can't even imagine how long or how wide I have to practice to get closer to a similar level as you are to be able to just look at the query and see what was wrong. Thank you again!!!

Comment: Well spotted. This is something that escaped me. The DBMS should of course raise an error, because the user name is not functionally dependent on the outer-joined user ID, A flaw in the DBMS, probably MySQL's notorious cheat mode where `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'` is not applied. @esentai: make sure you always work in ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode in order to have the DBMS tell you when your aggregation query is invalid.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner could it because I was using sqlite not mysql or postgres?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner what would be the best way to turn only_full_group_by mode? is it something I have to set in config file?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner If `users.id` is the primary key, then `users.name` should be functionally dependent.

Comment: Oh, sorry I confused the DBMS. In SQLite there is no such mode. So it really is a bug, not a mere wrong setting, in the DBMS.

Comment: @Barmer: Correct. Your `GROUP BY users.id` is valid. The original `GROUP BY events.user_id` is invalid and should have raised an error.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner SQLite is similar to MySQL without `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`. It doesn't enforce that requirement. See the section about "bare columns" in https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html

Comment: @ThorstenKettner It's even worse. SQLite has a special case if you use `MIN()` or `MAX()`. The bare columns will be taken from the row with the minimum/maximum value. So this makes the erroneous queries like `SELECT name, MIN(somecol)` do what the programmers intuitively expect it to do.

Comment: Yep, I learned about that bare columns thing recently. But it is well documented as an enhancement, so I am fine with this. As to ignoring functional dependency one has to read between the lines in their docs. You are right, they let the invalid aggregation pass and simply call the bare column `name` in OP's query "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a nested `SELECT`, this should return `null` for the `users` without any event:

```
select 
    u.name, 
    SELECT(
      group_concat(content)  
        FROM 
      events 
        WHERE 
      userId = u.id
    ) as events 
from 
    users u
order by 
    u.id
```